# Aiogram3 не работает callback совместно с message | Python

Tags: python, aiogram-3.x

У меня есть callback который на вход принимает нажатия по inline кнопке и он должен после нажатия изменить сообщение на "введите город" и далее ждать когда пользователь введет название после чего сохранить его в пременную.

**Callback**:

```
@dispatcher.callback_query(F.data == "search")
async def weather_search(callback: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext, message: Message):
   await callback.answer()   
   await state.set_state(city.city_search)
   await callback.message.edit_text('Введите название города:')
   await state.update_data(city_search=message.text)
   data = await state.get_data()
   await callback.message.answer("скоро будет...")
```

**Ошибка**:

```
TypeError: weather_search() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
```